# Kerberos: kadmin not working properly

Tags: kerberos

I have some trouble in getting my kadmin to work. Everything is fine in kadmin.local, but whenever I use kadmin, it seems it is using the kadm5.acl file, but isn't.

I have in this file:
$ cat /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl

```
 */admin@HADOOP.COM *
```

kadmin can connect to the kdc server correctly, and dns lookup and reverse dns is working also.

My krb5.conf is like this:
$ cat /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kdc.conf

```
[kdcdefaults]
    kdc_ports = 750,88

[realms]
    HADOOP.COM = {
        admin_keytab = FILE: /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.keytab
        kadmind_port = 749
        kdc_ports = 750,88
        max_life = 10h 0m 0s
        max_renewable_life = 7d 0h 0m 0s
        database_name = /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/principal
        acl_file = /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl
        #key_stash_file = /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/.k5.HADOOP.COM
}
```

and $ cat /etc/krb5.conf

```
[logging]
    default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
    kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
    admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]  
    default_realm = HADOOP.COM
    dns_lookup_realm = false 
    dns_lookup_kdc = false
    ticket_lifetime = 24h
    forwardable = yes

[realms]
    HADOOP.COM = {
    kdc = evl2400469.eu.verio.net:88  
    admin_server = evl2400469.eu.verio.net:749
    default_domain = hadoop.com 
}

[domain_realm]
    .hadoop.com = HADOOP.COM
    hadoop.com = HADOOP.COM
```

So when I try to perform an operation such as add a principal, or get the list of principals I get :
kadmin:  listprincs
get_principals: Operation requires ``list'' privilege while retrieving list.
kadmin:  getprivs
current privileges: GET ADD MODIFY DELETE

I really don't know where is the problem in my configuration.

I even tried to get a ticket before using kadmin console:
$ klist

```
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0 Default principal:
 kadmin/admin@HADOOP.COM

 Valid starting     Expires            Service principal 05/21/14
 10:13:34  05/21/14 13:13:34  krbtgt/HADOOP.COM@HADOOP.COM
         renew until 05/22/14 10:13:34


 Kerberos 4 ticket cache: /tmp/tkt0 klist: You have no tickets cached
```

Thanks a lot for your help on that :)

Answer (score 3):

Try editing `/var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl` with

```
*/admin@HADOOP.COM   *
```

The `kadmind` daemon needs to be restarted in order for changes in the ACL file to become active:

```
service kadmind restart
```

Comment: A little explanation would help this answer greatly. It also helps readability to format your code. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for the format syntax.

Comment: Since then I didn't renew my server, so I can't test the solution.

I am sure I had the right ACL though and did a mistake in writing it here.

Anyway, I agree if that was the case it would have solved it, but I cannot validate the solution.